# Writing is not permitted error when attempting to subscribe to CBCharacteristic

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an App that communicates with a Bluetooth LE device and so I'm using CoreBluetooth to do this.

The peripheral I'm using exposes 1 service which has two characteristics a serial port FIFO characteristic which supports indication/notification/write/write no response; and a serial port credit characteristic which supports write.

From my reading I gather that the characteristic that I need to subscribe to is the FIFO one but when I call `[_connectedPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];` I get a `Writing is not permitted` error.

I checked the characteristic's properties and it has the `Read`, `WriteWithoutResponse`, `Notify`, and `Indicate` properties.

This is the first time I've used CoreBluetooth and I'm a bit of a bluetooth noob so it's probably something obvious I've overlooked but any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
#define SDL440S_SERVICE @"2456E1B9-26E2-8F83-E744-F34F01E9D701"
#define SDL440S_CHARACTERISTIC @"2456E1B9-26E2-8F83-E744-F34F01E9D703"

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"Did connect %@", peripheral.name);
    // _connectedPeripheral is a property...
    if (_connectedPeripheral != peripheral) {
        _connectedPeripheral = peripheral;
    }
    _connectedPeripheral.delegate = self;
    [_connectedPeripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SDL440S_SERVICE]]];
}

#pragma mark - <CBPeripheralManager>

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    if (peripheral == _connectedPeripheral) {
        for (CBService *service in _connectedPeripheral.services) {
            if ([service.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:SDL440S_SERVICE]) {
                [_connectedPeripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SDL440S_CHARACTERISTIC]] forService:service];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if ([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:SDL440S_CHARACTERISTIC]) {
            // Subsribe to characteristic
            [_connectedPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}

// Getting values

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error changing note state for char: %@.\nError: %@", characteristic, error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you obtain `characteristic`? From the `didDiscoverCharacteristics` delegate method?

Comment: Exactly. I discover the peripheral I'm interested in, then discover the service I'm interested in, then the characteristics of the service use that reference to the characteristic to subscribe to notifications.

Comment: I'm using the protocol defined by the company that makes the component [here](http://support.connectblue.com/display/PRODBTSPA/connectBlue+Low+Energy+Serial+Port+Service)

Comment: Which delegate method gives you the error message?. An error about writing doesn't make sense for a setNotify operation.

Comment: It's the `didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:error:` delegate for `CBPeripheralDelegate`: `- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error changing note state for char: %@.\nError: %@", characteristic, error.localizedDescription);
    }
}`

Comment: How are you storing `characteristic`? Is it a property or an ivar?  Can you show the code where you try and setNotifyValue ?

Comment: I'll update my question. Sorry not to reply for a while. I'm not storing `characteristic` I'm just using the argument as it comes through the delegate method.

Comment: Try storing the discovered characteristic in a property. You will find that the characteristic is being released. Also get into the habit of using `self.property` rather than `_property`. You should only use `_property` when you specifically need to bypass the settler/getter.

Comment: thanks. ill give it a shot and let you know how it goes

Comment: So I tried that. I changed all the `_property`s to `self.property`s and  I also retain the `CBService` and the `CBCharacteristic` but I'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference if anyone comes across this problem, it was to do with the device's ***credit*** characteristic.

The service which I was interested in exposed two characteristics a ***credit*** characteristic and a ***FIFO*** characteristic. (I understand that a credit characteristic is standard issue.) The problem was that I had to write the maximum amount of data that i wanted to receive to the credit characteristic before i could then receive and write data to the FIFO characteristic.

I.e.:

```
unsigned char buf[1] = {/*relevant data here...*/};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:1];
[peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:creditCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

Comment: can you expand on this? I don't understand this.

Comment: I was communicating with a device that exposed two characteristics ([see here for more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)). The FIFO characteristic was the one which dealt with the data I was interested in, however, you have to notify the device (via the credit characteristic) that you want to begin communication.

Comment: Would i be able to send you my code so you can have a look at it? It is so frustrating as it works 50% of the time!!!

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be if you opened a new SO question. Posted your code there and then put the link to that question as a comment here.

Comment: How can I identify which characteristic is Credit ou FIFO?

Comment: @Tom Calmon honestly I can't remember now, it's been a while since I did anything with Core Bluetooth. Have you tried exploring the characteristics properties.

Comment: @RASS Yes, I did. I discovered some services about device information, which I ignored them, and one that interests me. My problem is that all of the characteristics that belongs to this service has value null and I cannot set notify characteristic changes because "Write is not permitted". Thank you for replying! :)

Comment: So write is not permitted because of the credit. However it seems that there may be other issues with your setup if characteristics are null. At the end of the day devices can be different so you may need to speak with the manufacturer. That's what I did.